# Back from the Dark Side

Tags: star-wars

In all the material that I've covered from the Star Wars Universe, apart from Vader, I have not read of any one who came to the Light Side of the Force after being exposed to the Dark Side.
Given that my knowledge is limited, I would like to ask whether there has been any one who came to the Light Side of the Force after experiencing the Dark Side?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the EU of Star Wars, but it seems that this question might quickly devolve into a list of answers.

Comment: Do you mean anyone who was never a Jedi (just a normal being), fell to the dark side, and then turned to the light (thus excluding fallen Jedi)? To my knowledge, there are none of these. But there are numerous redeemed Jedi

Comment: in the games http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revan

Comment: This is honestly something I disliked about the Expanded Universe. Just about everyone takes a trip to the dark side and comes back redeemed at some point of the story. The movied made it very clear that Anakin's redemption was pretty much unprecedented. After all Yoda says "If once you start down the dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny" instead of "if once you start down the dark path, you still have 75% chance of leaving it again".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In fact, [Redemption/Atonement](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_side_of_the_Force#Stage_4%3a_Redemption.2FAtonement) happen quite often. Even [Luke](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker#Return_of_the_Emperor) made his own journey in the Dark Side. And There is many others examples, like [Darth Caedus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Caedus#Last_days) and [Kyp Durron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyp_Durron#Atonement).

Answer (score 7):

Well, one example would be [Darth Caedus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Caedus), aka Jacen Solo; he went back and forth a few times.  It's not an uncommon theme for someone to be tempted (or pushed, as in Jacen's case), go over to the Dark for a while, and come back. In Jacen's case, he swung back again, and ended up

> dying while on the Dark side

but a number of characters have spent time on both sides.

If you can add more detail to the question, I might be able to provide a more accurate; Luke spent time yielding to the Dark Side in the original trilogy, but didn't actually go over.  Does he count?  Are you looking only for those who self-identified as Dark (i.e., Dark Jedi, The Sith, Bando Gora, etc.), or are you looking at those who wavered, but stayed light?  And are you looking for ones that had a Dark origin, or only ones that went that way at some point? Also, what degree of Canon?

There are some pretty funky examples of each; the Star Wars game, for example, reference the '[Light Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Sith)' who are trained in the Dark Side, but reject it for the light. (The [Dark Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Jedi) is a bad term, as it contains several groups, but it originally referred to the Jedi equivalent; those who fell from the Light.)

Comment: I'm not down-voting yet, but please remove Mara Jade. She VERY VERY explicitly was explained in Zahn's books to have NEVER been on the Dark Side. She served the Emperor but she was basically at that point literally a tool - like a hammer. She was a Force user but neither Light or Dark. (don't have a quote handy but she discussed it with Luke. I think my comment is a paraphrase of Luke's explanation)

Comment: @dvk - Well, I was reading the question to ask if anyone with experience with the Dark Side came to the Light, and I'd say being there while it was in use gave her considerable experience with it, even if she didn't use it directly herself.  But, looking at the question, I have a feeling I was being too literal.  Editing.

Answer (score 6):

Since osdamv unfortunately declined to post "Revan" as an answer, I will.

> [Revan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Revan), renowned as "The Revanchist" and dreaded as the Sith Lord Darth Revan, was an eminent Jedi Knight turned conquering Dark Lord of the Sith until, **stripped of his true persona, he returned to the crumbling Jedi Order** and helped defeat the Sith Empire he had established

Revan was a fairly major figure in SW canon. Among other things, he:

- Defeated none other than Mandalore the Ultimate and won [Mandalorian Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_Wars) while a Jedi
- Took over Rakatan [Star Forge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Forge) while a Sith
- Started a [Jedi Civil War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Civil_War) while a Sith Dark Lord
- Driven Sith off of [Korriban](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Korriban) after becoming Jedi again (though involuntary, since he lost his memories)
- Was instrumental in helping Jedi win [Jedi Civil War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Civil_War), after his full memories were returned and he chose the Light side consciously.
- Later, was presumed dead while fighting Sith Empire.

Comment: I'd forgotten about him.. Perfect example :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Rajivari (post mortem), Ajunta Pall (post Mortem), Kel'eth Ur, Gav Daragon, Ulic Qel-Droma, Revan(though he seems to have fallen again), Bastila, Malak (at moment of death), Sion, Atris, Possibly the SI and SW from TOR if LS is determined canon.

Skipping to more recent times...

Darth Gravid, Anakin Skywalker, Luke Skywalker, Kam Solusar, Kyle Katarn, Kyp Durron, Zekk, Jaina Solo, Ben Skywalker, Tahiri Veila (I'm not counting Caedus. I don't believe he was redeemed.)

Comment: Can you add some sources?

Answer (score 0):

In the *Dark Empire* storyline, Luke faces the Emperor reborn and decides he must face the Dark Side "from within." (Issue #2) He starts down that path and is brought back with Leia's help.